# Pause a class & wait for a sub-class to return a user input value before continuing

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt

How do you pause the current/main class and wait for a sub class to execute and return a user input value then continue the main class's execution?

**Example**: (search person from)
The user clicks the 'Search Person' button, mainClassController instantiate the searchPersonContoller, which return the user's selection(user double clicked a row in a QTableView). Then the mainClassController creates a new tab displaying the selected user

In the example above, how do you get the mainClassController to wait for the searchPersonContoller to return the value the user has selected?

**Attempt**: mainClass.py:

```
    self.searchPerson = searchPersonContoller()
    self.searchPerson.show()
    self.userSelection = searchPerson.getUserSelection()
        if self.userSelection > 0:
              #continue mainClass's code here
```

subClass.py:

```
def getUserSelection(self):
        self.selectionModel = self.ui.tbl.selectionModel()                  
        self.rowList = self.selectionModel.selectedRows()                               
        self.i = self.model.index(self.rowList[0].row(), 0, QtCore.QModelIndex())   
        self.close()
        return self.i.data()
```

The problem is the subclass doesn't have a value to return yet when the main class calls it, it should wait until the user has made a selection.

Comment: I'd have thought there's an "on selected" event you should listen for? (but I'm not familiar with qt)

Comment: You can't pause a class. You could paise a thread. Your question seem to be more like "How to ask for user input and wait for user selection using pyqt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon Clements pointed out in a comment above, there should be a signal the main class listen for. After playing around a bit this is what I came up with

mainClass.py:

```
    self.searchPerson = searchPersonContoller()
    self.searchPerson.show()
    self.searchPerson.ui.tbl.doubleClicked.connect(self.searchPersonReturn)

def searchPersonReturn(self):
     #continue mainClass's code here
```

Comment: The downside is that this closely couples the two classes. If later the searchPersonController's layout change and say the tbl got renamed or changed to a different object both classes will have to be updated

Comment: There is no close coupling involved here - the whole point of signals and slots is to avoid that. Calling a slot via a signal is no different than a normal method call.

Comment: Perhaps I misused the word 'coupling', but the fact remains that if for some reason the table in self.searchPerson.ui.tbl get renamed or changed to say a list then you will have to fix 2 classes. It would have been nice if the subclass managed everything and only return a value to the main class so that the main class didn't needed in depth knowledge of the objects within the subclass

Comment: The main class doesn't need any in depth knowledge - that is the main advantage of using signals. Rather than calling a very specialised method like `getUserSelection`, you just connect to a generic `doubleClicked` signal. Many widgets support such a signal, so there is an element of duck-typing involved here. The signal-slot mechanism actually promotes *weak* coupling, because the signal emitter and receiver don't need to make any assumptions about each other. Signals are like radio broadcasts: at any given time, there could be hundreds of different listeners, or none.

Comment: True, as long as the objects being referred to in the view's names stays constant. ui.tbl must stay ui.tbl and can not change to ui.lst without having to updating a bunch of classes which are listening to that particular object's signal. By the sound of it this is the most decoupled it is going to get.